# LUIS - Can I have 2 languages (Chinese and English) in same App, and still have good result?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am currently using MS LUIS for Chatbot.

Our country usually talks and chats using 2 languages, English and Chinese.

However, in LUIS I can only define one culture.

As a result, when my culture is set to English, and when I imports Chinese text, the confidence level is very low (e.g. English - 0.88, Chinese - 0.1).  The other way round is the same.

The situation is the same even after I did tokenize the Chinese text using library like JieBa or THULAC.

Therefore when I did testing, it is usually very easy to fall into an unrelated intent.

I would like to make LUIS recognize both English AND Chinese easily.  Are there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to make LUIS recognize both English AND Chinese easily. Are there any way to solve this problem?

Yes, the way is to separate your LUIS apps/projects, 1 for each language, and use a language detection before calling LUIS.

That's the official approach from LUIS docs (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-supported-languages?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#multi-language-luis-apps)):

> If you need a multi-language LUIS client application such as a chat
> bot, you have a few options. **If LUIS supports all the languages, you
> develop a LUIS app for each language**. Each LUIS app has a unique app
> ID, and endpoint log. If you need to provide language understanding
> for a language LUIS does not support, you can use Microsoft Translator
> API to translate the utterance into a supported language, submit the
> utterance to the LUIS endpoint, and receive the resulting scores.

For the language detection you can use `Text Analytics API` from Microsoft Cognitive Services for example to get the text language, and then with this result query the right LUIS app.

How to use it?

- Documentation of Language detection in Text Analytics API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/how-tos/text-analytics-how-to-language-detection?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365)
- Text analytics API: [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c7)

Comment: Thank you @Nicolas.  I read that line too.  But the problem is that how do we switch back and forth with different LUIS app ID if visitor suddenly uses different languages?  Or we simply let user to choose a language first and then we proceed over there?  Thank you

Comment: I think there is already the reply in my answer: use Text Analytics on each sentence so you have the language check everytime.
If you already know that the user will not change, you can get it from the beginning of the chat (by passing the value with backchannel, or asking the user, or any other mean)

Comment: Understood.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicolas mentioned above you can use [Multilanguage chat application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-supported-languages#multi-language-luis-apps) with separate LUIS apps for each culture.
In order to have single LUIS application, you could use the [Translator Text API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/translator-text-api/) to translate all incoming messages before they're sent to LUIS. In this case you'll want to use middleware to handle the translation before your LUIS Recognizer is called. You can also use middleware to translate your bot's response so you don't have to use additional localization inside of your bot

[Tokenizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-supported-languages#tokenization) in LUIS is different for each language in LUIS.

In the [zh-cn culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-supported-languages#chinese-support-notes), LUIS expects the simplified Chinese character set instead of the traditional character set.

Here is one more [sample](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/ChooseLanguageBot) where you can select a language from the bot and continue the consversation as required.

Comment: Thank you @Jyotsna, I read that line also.  If we use MS translation service we can stick to one language.  But I wonder how would be the translation performance.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation and several testings, I guess I found a way on how to do that properly:

First of all, I am currently using **MS BotFramework - NodeJS (3.14.0)** version to create my Bot.

And in `botbuilder` class, you have a function called `IntentDialog`, it accepts **[a list of recognizers](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.iintentdialogoptions.html#recognizers)**.  So I wrote something like this:

In `luis.js`

```
const builder = require("botbuilder")

// Setting for LUIS.ai
// Universal API key for both apps
let luisAPIKey = process.env.LuisAPIKey;

// First assign variables for Chinese LUIS app
let luisAppId_Chi = process.env.LuisAppId_Chi;
let luisAPIHostName_Chi = process.env.LuisAPIHostName_Chi || 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';
let LuisModelUrl_Chi = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName_Chi + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId_Chi + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey + '&verbose=true';

// Then assign variables for English LUIS app
let luisAppId_Eng = process.env.LuisAppId_Eng;
let luisAPIHostName_Eng = process.env.LuisAPIHostName_Eng || 'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com';
let LuisModelUrl_Eng = 'https://' + luisAPIHostName_Eng + '/luis/v2.0/apps/' + luisAppId_Eng + '?subscription-key=' + luisAPIKey + '&verbose=true';

// Return an object with 2 attributes: Chi for Chinese LUIS and Eng for English LUIS
let luis = {};
luis.chi = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl_Chi);
luis.eng = new builder.LuisRecognizer(LuisModelUrl_Eng);

module.exports = luis;
```

In `app.js`

```
const luis = require("./luis")
builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [luis.chi, luis.eng] });
```

And when I tested in botEmulator, it seems that it will first check LUIS Chi app, and then go to LUIS Eng app.

I don't know what is the criteria/threshold that this recognizer used to controls whether jumps to another app or not.  But at present it works for me to certain extend.  It is not accurate by at least a good(?) start.  :D

No MS Text translation API need.

By the way, the code will look nicer if I can get the `topIntent` and LUIS path right in `session` variable.

Hope it helps someone.